# How to set individual element of an array to Empty

Tags: java, arrays, excel, vba

**Background:** As a Java programmer, in order to familiarize myself with VBA, I am creating a VBA implementation of the Java `ArrayList`. The class is almost complete, but I am having trouble implementing the `remove(int index)` method.

**Question: How do I empty a single element in an array.**

In Java, I would use `arr[index] = null`. In VBA, I tried `Set arr[index] = Nothing`. The result was that the `index`-th element was not empty, but a `Nothing Object` (see the screenshot of my immediate window below). So, what is  the proper syntax to ensure that `elementData(0)` is `Empty` at the end of my function call?

[image: Immediate Window]

My full function code is below.

```
Public Function removeIndex(index As Long) As Variant
    rangeCheck (index) 'verify that index is in-bounds

    modCount = modCount + 1

    Dim oldValue As Variant
    oldValue = elementData(index) 

    Dim numMoved As Long
    numMoved = size - index - 1
    If numMoved > 0 Then
        'move the remaining elements left one
        arrayCopy elementData, index + 1, elementData, index, numMoved
    End If

    size = size - 1
    Set elementData(size) = Nothing
    remove = oldValue
End Function
```

Comment: Your list there says its a variant, could be any kind of variable. What happens if you set it to vbEmpty, vbNullString or ""?

Comment: Why is this tagged as Java?